# How to know the frequency usage of a column name in MySQL script?

Tags: mysql

I have a long MySQL stored procedure and it's mainly pointing to a big table. I would like to know if there's a way to analyze this stored procedure to know the frequency usage of a column (field name) in this big table. Reason being i would like to strip-off any columns which is not used in my procedure/script to reduce the space usage.

For example in mySQL procedure:
Select columnA, columnB from tableA;
Select columnA, columnD from tableA;

In my big tableA, all the available columns are: columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD, columnE.

The column usage that i would like to know (at least if it's mentioned in my procedure):
columnA - 2
columnB - 1
columnC - 0
columnD - 1
columnE - 0

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Save the procedure code to a text file. It's probably already in a text file if it's as long as you say, because I would think it should be under source control.

Open a bash shell.

Search for each column name, one by one, with `grep -c` which counts occurrences.

```
$ grep -c "columnA" myprocedure.sql
2

$ grep -c "columnB" myprocedure.sql
1

$ grep -c "columnC" myprocedure.sql
0

$ grep -c "columnD" myprocedure.sql
1

$ grep -c "columnE" myprocedure.sql
0
```

Some tasks in software development are things you'll only do once, so they are best done with the simplest command you can use, even if that makes the task kind of repetitive.

If you had to do this frequently, you could come up with some more automation, but don't invest the time unless it's something that has to be done a lot.